# Mapbox gl draw add name to polygon

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-marker

I am playing around with mapbox one of the things im trying to figure out is how to set a name on a polygon that i have just created.  I have a feature collection and  for each feature i have a name  but i cant figure out how to display the name on the polygon.

Answer (score 3):

In general, if you'd like to display GeoJSON features along with labels in your Mapbox GL JS map, you will need to add two layers to your map referencing the GeoJSON source. One layer will be of type [`fill`](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/layers/#fill) to display the polygons themselves, and the other will be of type [`symbol`](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/layers/#symbol) to display the text for the labels.

[This example](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/geojson-markers/) demonstrates how to add a `symbol` layer with `text-field`s containing the names of the `Point` features in the GeoJSON source. If you have the coordinates for each polygon where you'd like the name to be displayed, you can follow this example to add the names after adding your polygons with a `fill` layer.

Otherwise, you will need to compute the coordinates of the centroid of each polygon where you would like the names to be added. For this, you can use [Turf's `centroid` method](http://turfjs.org/docs/#centroid) on each polygon in your `FeatureCollection` to generate said coordinates and add the `symbol` layer representing each feature's name with the resulting coordinates.

Comment: could you provide more detail as to how to use the polygon's centroid with the symbol layer? Assuming centroid is a property on the polygon (tile), Is there a property that can specify the coordinates for the text .e.g, `text-position: ['get', 'centroid']`?